# Shortest distance between two different helix lines

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

I have two helix lines with center distance from each other. The lines had different rotational directions and radii and I'm interested to find a mathematical way to find the shortest distance between them. The lines can be described as follows:

Helix 1:
\begin{align}
x_1 &= R_1\cos (u) \\
y_1 &= R_1\sin (u) \\
z_1 &= c_1  u
\end{align}

Helix 2:
\begin{align}
x_2 &= R_2\cos (v) + \text{CenterDistance} \\
y_2 &= R_2\sin (v) \\
z_2 &= c_2  v
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please provide some context for this question?  Where did you encounter it?  What tools are you expected to use?  Is this for a particular class?  If so, which class?  Editing your question to include additional context will improve the chances that someone is able to provide an answer which actually meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The projections to the $xy$-plane are circles of radius $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively. Hence the distance is certainly at least $|R_1-R_2|$.
But for $u=0$, we verify that  $|R_1-R_2|$ is actually achieved.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I typed the wrong angle for line 2. it should be a different value. Have corrected it now (v instead of u).